# How to echo the elements of an XML in a predefined order using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

How can I output the XML elements in a predefined order? A possible solution of an array style it would be great if there is something like this.

I have a lot of XMLs with different names for elements that will be transformed the same time but as you can see they will all echoed the same. My problem is that their order is not correct and I want them in the same order just like

```
id, name, description, price, image, url, category, category_id, shopid
```

This is my XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:include href="identity.xsl"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <products>
            <xsl:for-each select="file">
                <xsl:apply-templates 
                    select="document(.)/*//product">
                    <xsl:with-param name="file" select="."/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </products>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="product">
        <xsl:param name="file"/>
        <xsl:copy>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>

            <xsl:if test="not(id)">
                <id><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></id>
            </xsl:if>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>

            <catid><xsl:value-of select="category/@id"/></catid>
            <shopid><xsl:value-of select="$file"/></shopid>

        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="title">
  <name>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
  </name>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="price_with_vat">
  <price>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
  </price>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="link">
  <url>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
  </url>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="category/@id
        | product/@id | availability | manufacturer | shipping | sku | ssku | thumbnail | stock | weight | mpn | instock"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using the Identity Transformation, you can define the order of the output elements by applying the templates singularly. Example:

```
<xsl:template match="product">
    <xsl:param name="file"/>
    <xsl:copy>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>

        <xsl:if test="not(id)">
            <id><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></id>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="name"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="description"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="price"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="image"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="url"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="category"/>

        <catid><xsl:value-of select="category/@id"/></catid>
        <shopid><xsl:value-of select="$file"/></shopid>

    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks! (you forgot to close the tag though )

Comment: What a shame this is what happens answering in the sleepy morning. I'm on holiday with worst connection ever.  I'm glad to whom will edit that thanks

Comment: I feel you for the holidays issue. Thanks again!